# Append any further columns to the first three columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am copying an excerpt of a badly formatted Excel sheet (with pd.read_clipboard). This is about 120 columns wide, with different column lengths. After every third column the next column should be appended to the very first one. So I should end up with three columns.

I setup a sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "1": np.random.randint(900000000, 999999999, size=5),
    "2": np.random.choice( ["A","B","C", np.nan], 5),
    "3": np.random.choice( [np.nan, 1], 5),

    "4": np.random.randint(900000000, 999999999, size=5),
    "5": np.random.choice( ["A","B","C", np.nan], 5),
    "6": np.random.choice( [np.nan, 1], 5)
})
```

Which results in something like this:

```
  1         2   3   4         5   6
0 925846412 nan 1.0 994235729 nan NaN 
1 991877917 B   1.0 970766032 nan NaN 
2 931608603 B   NaN 937096948 B   NaN 
3 977083128 A   NaN 974190653 B   1.0 
4 937344792 nan NaN 972948910 B   1.0
```

This is what I have so far:

```
col_counter = 0
df_neu = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C"])

for column in df.columns:
    if col_counter == 3:
        col_counter = 0

    if col_counter == 0:
        # set_trace()
        df_neu["A"] = df_neu["A"].append(df[column]).reset_index(drop = True)
    elif col_counter == 1:
        df_neu["B"] = df_neu["B"].append(df[column]).reset_index(drop = True)
    elif col_counter == 2:
        df_neu["C"] = df_neu["C"].append(df[column]).reset_index(drop = True)

    col_counter +=1
```

The required result would be:

```
  A         B   C
0 925846412 nan 1.0
1 991877917 B   1.0
2 931608603 B   NaN 
3 977083128 A   NaN
4 937344792 nan NaN 
5 994235729 nan NaN 
6 970766032 nan NaN 
7 937096948 B   NaN 
8 974190653 B   1.0 
9 972948910 B   1.0
```

But I am receiving the following:

```
  A         B   C
0 925846412 NaN NaN 
1 991877917 NaN NaN 
2 931608603 NaN NaN 
3 977083128 NaN NaN 
4 937344792 NaN NaN
```

So only the first column from the very first iterations gets appended. Any other columns are ignored.

So my questions are:

1. What is my mistake?
2. How can I solve it?
3. Is there maybe a better approach? It "feels" like a rather "unsexy" way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex` in columns by integer and modulo division by array created by length of columns and then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for remove `MultiIndex`:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "1": np.random.randint(900000000, 999999999, size=5),
    "2": np.random.choice( ["A","B","C", np.nan], 5),
    "3": np.random.choice( [np.nan, 1], 5),

    "4": np.random.randint(900000000, 999999999, size=5),
    "5": np.random.choice( ["A","B","C", np.nan], 5),
    "6": np.random.choice( [np.nan, 1], 5)
})
print (df)
           1    2    3          4  5    6
0  960189042    B  NaN  991581392  A  1.0
1  977655199  nan  1.0  964195250  A  1.0
2  961771966    A  NaN  969007327  B  1.0
3  955308022    C  1.0  973316485  A  NaN
4  933277976    A  1.0  976749175  A  NaN
```

---

```
arr = np.arange(len(df.columns))
df.columns = [arr // 3, arr % 3]

df = df.stack(0).sort_index(level=[1, 0]).reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = ['A','B','C']
print (df)
           A    B    C
0  960189042    B  NaN
1  977655199  nan  1.0
2  961771966    A  NaN
3  955308022    C  1.0
4  933277976    A  1.0
5  991581392    A  1.0
6  964195250    A  1.0
7  969007327    B  1.0
8  973316485    A  NaN
9  976749175    A  NaN
```

Your solution working if append to `Series` and last create `DataFrame` by contructor:

```
col_counter = 0
a,b,c = pd.Series(),pd.Series(),pd.Series()

for column in df.columns:
    if col_counter == 3:
        col_counter = 0

    if col_counter == 0:
        # set_trace()
        a = a.append(df[column]).reset_index(drop = True)
    elif col_counter == 1:
        b = b.append(df[column]).reset_index(drop = True)
    elif col_counter == 2:
        c = c.append(df[column]).reset_index(drop = True)

    col_counter +=1

df_neu = pd.DataFrame({"A":a, "B":b, "C":c})
print (df_neu)
           A    B    C
0  960189042    B  NaN
1  977655199  nan  1.0
2  961771966    A  NaN
3  955308022    C  1.0
4  933277976    A  1.0
5  991581392    A  1.0
6  964195250    A  1.0
7  969007327    B  1.0
8  973316485    A  NaN
9  976749175    A  NaN
```

Comment: Perfect! I still have to work a bit on your solution with the multi index to fully understand it. But I do understand now, what my mistakes were with my initial approach.

Comment: With new solutions come new questions. How could it be done to add e.g. a column "D" that includes an indicator showing from which column triple the values come from? So row 0-4 would have the value "0" in column "D" and 5-9 would have "1" etc.

Comment: @SLglider - Can you create new question? Because not easy.

Comment: Follow up can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54183920/append-any-further-columns-to-the-first-three-columns-and-indicate-the-triple-co